# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

getting this error while passing this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Protected = (children) => {
const id = localStorage.getItem('id')
if (!id) {
console.log(id)
return <Navigate to="login" replace />
}
return children 
}

 export default Protected
```

passing the data like

```
 localStorage.setItem('id', response.data[0].idmain_table)
```

i am rendring dashbord route in proteted

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <HashRouter>
    <Suspense fallback={loading}>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" element={<Login 
       />} />
        <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" element={<Register />} />

        <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" element={<Page404 />} />
        <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" element={<Page500 />} />
        <Route
          path="*"
          name="Home"
          element={
            <Protected>
              <DefaultLayout />
            </Protected>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </HashRouter>
   )
 } 
  }
```

just using protected route to protect the dashbord or default layout but its giving me error
any help will be welcome

Comment: what are you rendering in protected? <Protected>what is here?</Protected>?

Comment: I think you want to extract children from props.  ```const Protected = ({ children }) => { ... }```. If you still run into an issue try wrapping children in a ```<View></View>```.

Comment: its default layout in it which i am protected in route i have updated in main code

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to render the `props` object.

You should destructure `children` from that object first.